# Unable to create an interface to mock Google Cloud Storage

Tags: go, google-cloud-platform

I'm trying to create an interface to abstract the google cloud storage.

I have the following interfaces:

```golang
type Client interface {
    Bucket(name string) *BucketHandle
    Close() error
}

type BucketHandle interface {
    Create(context.Context, string, *storage.BucketAttrs) error
    Delete(context.Context) error
    Attrs(context.Context) (*storage.BucketAttrs, error)
}
```

And the my code

```golang
type Bucket struct {
    handler Client
}

func NewStorage(ctx context.Context, bucketName string) Bucket {
    var bkt Bucket
    client, err := storage.NewClient(ctx)
    if err != nil {
        return Bucket{}
    }

    bkt.handler = client
    return bkt
}
```

I get the following error: `cannot use client (variable of type *storage.Client) as Client value in assignment: wrong type for method Bucket`

And goland shows the following

```
Cannot use 'client' (type *Client) as type Client Type does not implement 'Client' need method: Bucket(name string) *BucketHandle have method: Bucket(name string) *BucketHandle
```

I'm lost on why the types aren't the same.

Comment: Try compiling it with `go` rather than GoLand to get the proper error message with fully qualified types. Once you do that the error will make sense.

Comment: As an aside, and probably also somewhat related to what you want to achieve, do not use pointers to interfaces. `*I` where `I` is an interface type is rarely useful, and your case is not one of the rare ones.

Comment: Finally, to be able to do what you want, you'll have to create a thin wrapper around the storage.Client type that *will* implement your Client interface by providing methods that have signatures that match the interface method signatures *verbatim*.

Comment: here's an example if you need one: https://play.golang.com/p/WcvgIhqGoZV

Comment: Thanks @mkopriva that's perfect!

Answer (score 2):

> Cannot use 'client' (type *Client) as type Client Type does not
>   implement 'Client' need method: Bucket(name string) *BucketHandle have
>   method: Bucket(name string) *BucketHandle

There is nothing wrong with this error. The reason it seems misleading is because you have created an interface with the exact same name as a concrete struct in the library i.e., `BucketHandle`

Notice closely the difference between the return types in the two functions:

```
// In your interface, the return type is an interface that you created
Bucket(name string) *BucketHandle

// In the library, the return type is a concrete struct that exists in that lib
Bucket(name string) *BucketHandle
```

You will need to modify the `Client` interface to the following and it should work fine.

```
type Client interface {
    Bucket(name string) *storage.BucketHandle
    Close() error
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`storage.NewClient(ctx)` return *storage.Client. whereas you are trying to assign to Client, your Client should implement the methods which storage.Client implements

Client interface should be

```
type Client interface {
    Close() error
    ServiceAccount(ctx context.Context, projectID string) (string, error)
}
```

and bucket can be

```
type Bucket struct {
    handler Client
}
```

check here https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-go/blob/master/storage/storage.go#L101

Comment: Thanks, but with that I get the following error ```cannot use client (type *"cloud.google.com/go/storage".Client) as type *Client in assignment:
 *Client is pointer to interface, not interface```
So I assume I'm doing something wrong in the way I'm implementing the interface?

Comment: @Paulo try with *storage. Client.

Comment: @anand the whole point of the question is how to use the interface abstraction, as declared and presented in the question, instead of the concrete `*storage.Client` type.

Comment: @anand no you're wrong, you *can* assign it to an interface type whose method set is implemented by `*storage.Client` type itself.

Comment: correct! @mkopriva. thanks! it needs to implement the methods implemented in storage.Client